# Validate of the PasswordBox WPF after log out

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, passwords

I have validation of the password in my WPF app. I am using IDataErrorInfo interface for it. There is xml-code with the validation template:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,-30,20,0" Height="23" Width="250" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
            </Border>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Red" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" 
                        ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=Adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">!</TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="Adorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ErrorViewerItemTemplate" DataType="string" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="5" Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="red" Padding="2" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Label x:Name="passLabel" Content="Password" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,40,0,0" Height="23">
            <PasswordBox local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="True" 
            x:Name="passwordBox" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword>
                    <Binding Path="Password" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <NotifyDataErrorValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword>
            </PasswordBox>
        </Border>
</Grid>
```

Realization IDataErrorInfo interface for password:

```
class ConnectionSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _password;

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
        }
    }

... // realization INotifyPropertyChanged interface

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string errorMessage = String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                ...
                case "Password":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Validation error: Enter the data in the field";
                    }
                    else if (!RegexPasswordValid(Password))
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Validation error: The password does not match the template or short password (minimum 8 characters)";
                    }
                    break;
                 ...
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }

    private bool RegexPasswordValid(string value)
    {
        string pattern = @"^(\w{8,})$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        bool isRegexValid = (regex.IsMatch(value)) ? true : false;
        return isRegexValid;
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```

For binding of the password I use [PasswordBoxAssistant class](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html).

Validation of the login works correctly (at the first time, when user logging in),
[image]

but when user logs out - validation on login window doesn't work.
[image]

I have tryed to set `Mode="TwoWay"` for binding and `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
      ValidatesOnExceptions=True`, but it didn't fix my problem.

So, please help me fix it at least somehow.)

Comment: Are you sure that the "ConnectionSettings" is discarded at logout and newly created for login? In other words: Are you sure you don't have a valid password stored in your view-model?

Comment: @SvenBardos, yes, I have checked it.

Comment: @SvenBardos and I have the login and two fields more and I am checking of them in this way too. And after log out, I don't have the problem with them, but they are textboxes.